# Давайте проведём очередной выпуск видео чата сообщества!

Tags: обсуждение, видеочат

Довольно давно у нас не было выпусков видео чата сообщества. Если вы скучаете по нему также как и мы, то давайте попробуем что–то с этим сделать! Например, что вы думаете о том, чтобы провести очередной выпуск?

Если вы за, пожалуйста, подскажите:

1. На какую тему вы бы хотели увидеть выпуск?
2. Кого бы из участников вы хотели видеть в выпуске?
3. Хотели бы вы сами принять участие?

Ориентировочно, выпуск можно было бы провести в конце этого месяца. Будет очень здорово увидеть 2 - 4 участника сообщества в выпуске.

Буду рад вашим отзывам!

---

Следующий выпуск состоится 09.07.2020. Гостями станут модераторы сообщества: [Выпуск видеочата №9 с @A K и @Suvitruf - Andrei Apanasik 09.06.2020 в 11:01](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10591/6)

Comment: ЛГБТ участники сообщества, работники сферы айти из малых городов СНГ

Comment: Разработка игр. Хотелось бы пообщаться со StrangerintheQ, и другими разработчиками. Я бы принял участие.

Comment: "День из жизни управляющего международными сообществами Stack Overflow". Хотелось бы видеть Николаса и кого-то из его текущих соратников. Участия бы не принял, но с интересом посмотрел/послушал.

Comment: @Kromster Спасибо за предложение! Пока тема игр лидирует =) Как мне кажется, было бы здорово после долгого перерыва встретиться именно участниками. За одно обсудим кого из сотрудников вы бы хотели увидеть в выпуске.

Comment: @yolosora Предложение очень здоровское! К сожалению, я вряд ли смогу сделать запрос, который выберет таких участников (чтобы предложить им принять участие в выпуске). Подскажите, есть ли у вас кто–либо на уме? Готовы ли сами принять участие, если попадаете в одну из категорий?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky к сожалению нет никого на примете. Оставил комментарий чисто в качестве сигнала о том, что кому-то было бы интересно посмотреть подобный видео чат и, возможно, отзовутся желающие скрывающиеся в тени :)

Comment: @yolosora Согласен! Я бы с удовольствием послушал, как живет IT в небольших городах России.

Comment: а я относительно новый участник, я не знаю, что такое *выпуск видео чата сообщества*. Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: @Антон Добрый день! В двух словах: несколько участников (гости выпуска) и я встречаемся в обусловленное время, я задаю ребятам несколько вопросов в течении часа, они отвечают, мы это все записываем или транслируем на YouTube. Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на вопросы по метке [meta-tag:видеочат].

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky спасибо! Обязательно посмотрю! Жалко у меня пока мало репы - мечтаю модератором стать... а заявку можно подавать после 10000?