# Выпуск видеочата №9 с @A K и @Suvitruf - Andrei Apanasik 09.07.2020 в 11:01

Tags: обсуждение, видеочат

С радостью спешу поделиться, что мы планируем записать очередной выпуск видеочата сообщества в четверг 9-го июля 2020 года в 11:01 по московскому времени. Гостями девятого выпуска будут наши дорогие модераторы:

- [@A K](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213987/a-k). Андрей окончил Волгоградский Политех по специальности "Робототехника и станки с ЧПУ", работает старшим программистом в Москве. Увлечения – музыка, пение, психология.
- [@Suvitruf - Andrei Apanasik](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/15479/suvitruf-andrei-apanasik). Андрей окончил айтишную специальность. Занимается то бекендом, то геймдевом, рассказывает про свой опыт [в личном блоге](https://suvitruf.ru/). Заядлый геймер, пишет про игры и связанные темы с играми на dtf.ru.

Тема этого выпуска — модерирование сообществ.

#### Пожалуйста, задавайте ваши вопросы!

Расскажите, что бы вам хотелось узнать о модерировании сообществ у участников выпуска? Поскольку одна из главных целей выпуска — познакомиться друг с другом, пожалуйста, также задавайте вопросы ребятам про их профессиональный опыт и личные проекты. Пожалуйста, задавайте ваши вопросы заранее, отправив их мне на почту (nicolas.chabanovsky@stackoverflow.com) или опубликуйте комментарий или ответ в данном вопросе.

---

Пока я не знаю, получится ли организовать трансляцию. В тоже время, запись будет обязательно доступна.

---

[Ссылка на трансляцию — YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gJuhEcD4nqo)

Comment: А где потом можно посмотреть?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica На канал на Ютюбе добавлю запись, если не получится организовать стрим. Ссылку добавлю в этот вопрос.

Comment: OK..............

Comment: С удовольствием посмотрю!

Comment: задал на почту 2 вопроса!

Comment: Видеочат подразумевает подключение к нему других участников? Если "да", то где ссылочку найти?

Comment: @XelaNimed Рад вас видеть! Видеочат пройдет в Zoom, возможность интерактивно участвовать будет только у гостей. С другой стороны, с большой вероятностью мы будем транслировать выпуск на Youtube. Можно будет задать вопрос в чате =) Что думаете?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky хотелось бы конечно пообщаться. Но так как чат подразумевает именно общение, то хотелось бы иметь такую возможность, а не просто смотреть чью-то дискуссию между собой...

Comment: @XelaNimed Интересная идея. Можно будет попробовать в следующий раз! Как минимум, приходите гостем? =)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я б пришёл, но только куда?

Comment: @XelaNimed В следующий видеочат! =)

Comment: Мы в эфире! Пожалуйста, задавайте вопросы!

Comment: Очень быстро прошел час и осталось много незаданных и неотвеченных тем и вопросов. Но все равно, всем спасибо!

Comment: Мне формат понравился, но слишком мало времени. Может быть на регулярной основе это сделать? Тогда и вопросы можно было бы подбирать, и люди бы уже знали, да и не обязательно бы было только с модераторами общаться, а например устраивать что-то типа каких-либо докладов, aka хакатонов по какой-либо определённой тематике...

Comment: @XelaNimed так примерно и задумано с этими видеочатами, только редко организуется.

Comment: спасибо. очень хотелось их послушать

Comment: хха, я почему-то думал, что АК гораздо старше :)

Answer (score 5):

**Впечатления от встречи и от всех участников, в целом**

1. Живое общение, настоящие лица - это здорово.
2. Порадовала рассудительность участников при обсуждении рабочих вопросов по управлению сообществом.
3. Подтвердилось моё личное мнение, что вы на своём месте.

**Андрей Круглов** @A K

Всегда думал, что АК это от Туз, Король, а оно вон как...

1. Книгу, если надумал, то пиши, ибо трудолюбия по написанию сообщений здесь хватает, хватит и на неё. Нужно лишь определиться с направлением и содержанием.
2. Открытость это хорошо, но порой чрезмерные рассуждения тормозят принятия решений или и того хуже, ещё больше накаляют обстановку, как привёл в пример Андрей А.
3. Доводы и примеры из других областей деятельности (пример про судью, защитника, обвинителя) - это красиво.
4. Голос. Приятно слушать. Я бы посмотрел в сторону озвучивания, но после того как решится вопрос с качеством звука.

**Андрей Апанасик** @Suvitruf

1. Опять-таки, рассудительнее выглядишь, если можно так сказать, чем твой образ в Сети. Всё-таки не зря говорят, что "встречают по одёжке", влияние изображения учётки накладывает свой отпечаток на восприятие.
2. Про русский язык не забываем, да, мы же русское(-язычное) сообщество).
3. Деятельное участие на Мете - это хорошо, видна работа (неоплачиваемая) и то, что люди с ромбом держат руку на пул..., следят за сердцебиением сообщества, в общем.

**Николай Чабановский** @Nicolas Chabanovsky

1. Понравилось умение вести беседу в случаях, когда видно (ну или мне так показалось), что точка зрения собеседников отличается от твоей.
2. Хорошо, что вообще проводишь такие встречи.
3. Стало любопытно узнать побольше про наше сообщество с точки зрения чисел.

**Пожелания**

1. Больше качества и света.
2. Хороший звук. Его тоже не хватало.
3. Личное к Николаю: слишком много стен и потолка, а головы мало)