# Не хотели бы вы стать участником видеочата про выбор технологий в сегодняшнем динамичном мире?

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, видеочат

[Дмитрий Полянин](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/205037/?tab=profile) и [я](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/?tab=profile) в обозримом будущем планируем организовать [видеочат](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82) на тему:

> Что делать, что изучать, как программировать, когда в мире каждый год появляются 10 000 + новых технологий, а часть имеющихся устаревает?

Было бы очень здорово, если бы к нам присоединились еще один или два участника сообщества. Если вы хотите поделиться с коллегами своими мыслями на тему выбора технологий для проекта или что следует изучать, пожалуйста, напишите мне на почту о своем желании: nicolas.chabanovsky@stackoverflow.com Я свяжусь с вами, и мы обговорим удобное для вас время и интересующие вас темы.

Давайте рассказывать о себе, своих интересах и делиться своим жизненным опытом в видеоформате!

**Добавлено Дмитрием:**
Особенно хочется именно опытных участников - разработчиков с большим временным опытом разработки, кто уже выработал свой подход к этой теме: "Как правильно плавать в такой объёмной реке постоянно появляющихся, обновляющихся и устаревающих знаний в программировании и IT".

**Примерные вопросы:**

- Как выбирать что изучать и что использовать?
- Переходить ли на новую версию, которая сулит супер блага, но цена перехода не мала?
- Как вообще не потеряться в обилии этих технологий?
- Нужно ли изучать какую-то технологию прямо от А до Я, как это делалось раньше, например C#?
- Как строить программу что бы она не скатывалась в легаси, и что бы не устаревала, либо наименее быстро устаревала? Возможно ли такое?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь! Участвовать не сложно и очень увлекательно. Пожалуйста, напишите мне если у вас есть какие–либо вопросы! =)

Comment: расскажи, о чем вы будете говорить в первом чате

Comment: @nörbörnën добавил примерный список вопросов

Comment: Добавлю вопрос в список, если можно - "За чей счёт идут все эти эксперименты и неопробованные технологии, и каков профит заказчику от этого"

Comment: Есть какие то приблизительные даты, когда вы планируете этот чат?

Comment: я могу ошибаться, но кажется @XelaNimed [хотел участвовать](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10591/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0-9-%d1%81-a-k-%d0%b8-suvitruf-andrei-apanasik-09-07-2020-%d0%b2-1101#comment44759_10591) (просто пингую на всякий случай)

Comment: @tym32167 Разве пинг так работает?

Comment: @SKIP я упомянул его в комментарии, так что он получит оповещение об этом.

Comment: @tym32167 А получит ли, если он не отписывался в этом вопросе?

Comment: я бы добавил 2 момента, непосредственно связанных со Stack Overflow. // **1.** Вопросы вида «я хочу создать проект. Краткое описание планируемого проекта. Какие технологии лучше всего для него использовать?» Случается, что на ранних этапах разработки выбирают не те технологии, понимание чего приходит слишком поздно, когда переписывание окажется слишком затратным. Хотелось бы, чтобы Stack Overflow помогал разработчикам справляться и с этой проблемой.

Comment: **2.** Старые вопросы, на которые даны ответы, актуальные на момент появления вопросов, но устаревшие сейчас. Такие ответы порой имеют много плюсов, и люди, которые пришли на Stack Overflow посмотреть решение конкретной проблемы, могут избрать для своих целей их, а не более современные решения.

Спасибо.

Comment: А можете ещё рассмотреть вопрос, где лучше всего следить за обновлением технологий? Пресса, блоги, форумы, твиттер, официальные источники или ещё что. Потому что если с апдейтами ещё более-менее понятно, то как не пропустить релиз более удобного инструмента?

Comment: Не стесняться, так не стесняться. Я бы не хотел стать участником, так как как с такой повесткой оно скорее превратится в bullshit bingo.